# Erro C# System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

Boas com uma duvida neste codigo , ele na linha 14 da me um erro como podem ver na foto ...

Soluções ??

Obrigado[image: Erro]
Codigo:

```
using System;
public class Exercise052
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Cuantos datos reservo: ");
        int repeticiones = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        float numero;
        float[] listaNumeros = new float[repeticiones];

        for (int i = 1; i <= repeticiones; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Dime numero {0} para guardar en la lista: ", i);
            listaNumeros[i] = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.Write("Que numero comprueba en la lista? ");
        numero = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

        while (Console.ReadLine() != "end")
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= repeticiones; i++)
            {
                if (listaNumeros[i] == numero)
                    Console.WriteLine("El número {0} existe en la lista", numero);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o erro? Escreva na pergunta. Não use imagens.

Comment: O erro que aparece é "  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro na verdade não é no `Convert.ToSingle()` e sim no seu laço de repetição. Os indices de um array começam no 0 e não no 1, então quando chegar na ultima iteração vai dar o erro `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`, ou seja, o indice estava fora dos limites do vetor.

Se o vetor tem 5 posições por exemplo, a primeira posição é o `0` e a última é o `4`.

Para corrigir seu algorítmo, você deve trocar o seu `for` por:

```
for (int i = 0; i < repeticiones; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: Troquei o código e continua o mesmo erro .Mas obrigado pela resposta se tiver outra possivel hipotse agradecia.

Comment: O erro continua na mesma linha?

Comment: Sim , infelizmente

Comment: Testei o código no repl.it e funcionou perfeitamente. O link é este: https://repl.it/@natanfernandes1/WellmadeIllfatedProfiles

Comment: Tem toda a razão , eu estava a executar o programa antigo... Peço desculpa e obrigado por me ajudar.